# Perl - How to convert bitcoin private keys to addresses with elliptic curve math

Tags: perl, elliptic-curve, bitcoin

I have a large dump (~25K) of all the private keys from my bitcoin wallet, but I don't have a mapping to the associated addresses for each private key. I need the address before I can recreate the wallet because I need to skip some of the addresses and not add them to the new wallet.

I was pointed to a python tool that includes the conversion method: [pywallet](https://github.com/joric/pywallet/blob/master/pywallet.py), but I'd rather do this in Perl, so I can more easily script it. I also found these two JavaScript sites that do this: [bitaddress.org](http://bitaddress.org) and [brainwallet.org](http://brainwallet.org).

I found the following libraries on CPAN, which sound like they might be helpful to do this, but I have no idea how to plug the pieces together: [Math::EllipticCurve::Prime](http://metacpan.org/module/Math%3a%3aEllipticCurve%3a%3aPrime), [Crypt::OpenSSL::EC](http://metacpan.org/module/Crypt%3a%3aOpenSSL%3a%3aEC). The documentation for the former says it's really slow, the latter is probably faster because it uses a C library, but the documentation is confusing. I also found some elliptic curve code on [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Bitcoin/Elliptic_curve_arithmetic#Perl). And there used to be a Crypt::ECDSA on CPAN, but was deleted at some point.

So what's the best, and fast, way to get the bitcoin address from a private key using Perl?

Comment: *SO wouldn't let me add more links so here's the modules linkified: [Crypt::OpenSSL::EC](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Crypt-OpenSSL-EC/), [Math::EllipticCurve::Prime](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Math-EllipticCurve-Prime/).

Comment: even things deleted from CPAN are still available: http://backpan.perl.org/authors/id/B/BI/BILLH/Crypt-ECDSA-0.069.tar.gz

Comment: yes, but that still doesn't help me figure out how to do this

Comment: Added module links for you. Also you should [learn to use Markdown](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in your questions. ( It's a lot faster/easier to type and edit )

Comment: thanks. i copied the html directly from a question i tried posting to perlmonks, but they have a known permission denied bug when trying to submit question, so i couldn't ask there.

Answer (score 0):

You should check first this: https://github.com/grondilu/libbitcoin-perl - maybe will give your some ideas.